# Java Space Invader bullet movement

Tags: java, swing, animation, user-interface, jpanel

I am trying to code a Space Invader game to brush up on my skills that I have learned in AP Computer Science. I ran into a problem. When I press the spacebar (fire button) the animation of the bullet traveling to the top is not visible. Instead the bullet just appears on top of the screen from where you have fired from. This is the code that contains the firing of the bullet:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AlienInvader extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    Constants constant = new Constants();
    Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
    Sprite images = new Sprite();

    public void update() {
        timer.start();
        images.loadImage();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        g.drawImage(images.spaceship, constant.x, constant.y, null);
        g.drawImage(images.bullet, constant.bulletx, constant.bullety, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(constant.x);
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            constant.xvel = -1 * constant.STEP;
            repaint();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            constant.xvel = 1 * constant.STEP;
            repaint();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            constant.xvel = 0;
            constant.bulletx = constant.x;
            constant.bullety = constant.y;
            while (constant.bullety > 0) {
                constant.bullety = constant.bullety - 1;
                repaint();
            }
        }
        constant.x += constant.xvel;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            constant.xvel = -1;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            constant.xvel = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

How would I make it so the user can see the bullet traveling up the screen from when you fire?

Answer (score 3):

You've run into the "blocking the Event Dispatching Thread" problem, which seems to be a very common problem around here....

Basically while this code is executing....

```
while (constant.bullety > 0) {
    constant.bullety = constant.bullety - 1;
    repaint();
}
```

Nothing can be painted, because you are blocking the thread that is responsible for processing the repaints.

A `repaint` is a request that is made to the repaint manager to update a portion on the screen.  The repaint manager is designed for performance, so it will try and collapse all the various repaint requests down into as few calls as possible, and then add a repaint request onto the Event Dispatching Thread....

So, while you're block the EDT, nothing can be repainted.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

Now, to a solution.

There are many ways to achieve this.  Generally speaking, you need some kind of "engine" or "controller" that is capable of running the background, update the various objects in the game and render that result to the screen.

This presents a number of significant issues.  The first been, all interactions with the UI must be executed from within the context of the EDT.  This means, you should never create or update any UI component from outside the EDT.

The second is making sure you don't mutate any part of the game model that the renderer is depending on (since you don't actually control the repaint process).

This simplest solution would be to use a `BufferedImage`, which you could draw to it (within a background `Thread`).

This would allow you to update the game model, render the result to a backing buffer, re-sync that buffer to the UI and then do a small wait to allow the UI time to catch up.  Simple :D

Comment: Are you trying to say that I need to use a BufferedImage in order to add the image to the console? I have done that already. Here is the code:

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Sprite {
 
 BufferedImage spaceship, bullet;
 
 public void loadImage() {
  try {
   spaceship = ImageIO.read(new File("spaceship.png"));
   bullet = ImageIO.read(new File("bullet.png"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

}

Comment: No, I'm saying you need to use at least two `BufferedImage`s to renderer you entire game state.  One will be used by render to the screen (via one of the `paint` methods) and the other will be used by the game thread engine to update the state of all the objects in the world.  You would then swap the references, meaning that while you are updating the game state, anything painted by Swing won't get rendered prematurely.